# Listening to netTcpbinding other than port 808?

Tags: c#, wcf

Can I listen to netTcpbinding in **other** port than 808 ?

Im hosting on WAS under iis7.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can listen on another port.  808 is the "default", but you can use another port.  You'll have to make sure the service is using that port, and you may need to open the port in the firewall.  There may be IIS configuration issues as well - I can't recall off the top of my head and don't have an IIS installation to look at currently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have deployed apps on port other than 808. As Tim said make sure you have corrct port on firewall settings and make sure your IIS have that port setting in its Bindings.

to do that go to DefaultWebSite-> Advanced Settings->Bindings and make sure you got net.tcp:NewPort:*

where NewPort is your new port you want other than 808.